# Git Remove File From Being Indexed Locally But Not Remotely

Tags: git, github

I am using GitHub for a multi-server deployment, one it a production server and one is a development one. There are certain configuration files (let's call it config.php) that need to be server specific. However, for backup purposes we need the production's config file left on the GitHub server. However, on the dev server we need to keep to remove it from the git push/pull process so that it never gets uploaded to the server, or overwrote on git pull commands. How can I do this? Would adding it to .gitignore handle this process, or would that get replicated over to the production server.

For references the config file's location in relation to .git is /exampledirectory/config.php

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question: you can't.

If the config file is already tracked by git, you cannot ignore it only locally (this is why the cloned repository is a `clone`: it's really exactly the same content)

There is 3 options:

- You can remove the file from git ( `git rm exampledirectory/config.php --cached && git commit && git push`) but you will have then to connect to the remote server and restore that file (just one time). Now, if you want to change the production configuration, you will have to log in remotely.
- Alternatively, you can rename the file to config-default.php, and eventually add one post-update hook (and/or others, locally or remotely depending of your needs) to copy that file to config.php if a change is detected.

* an other alternative (and I use a similar solution) requires some development to change the way your config file is included, based on which environment you currently are (production, development or other) : for example if you add in your local vhost  `setEnv CUSTOM_ENV develop` , You can then use the following code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['CUSTOM_ENV']))
{
  $config = __DIR__.'/exampledirectory/'.$_SERVER['CUSTOM_ENV'].'/config.php';
  if (!file_exists($config))
    $config = false;
}

if (!$path)
{
  $config = __DIR__.'/exampledirectory/config.php';
}
require_once($config);
```

You can also base the environment definition on a file present somewhere in your disk ( an empty file named `.debug.inc`, your ip (127.0.0.1 when localhost) the value of a cookie you will set or anything you want.

on that example, the path `exampledirectory/develop` would probably be in the .gitignore , so all developpers can customize their own configuration without any problem. And you can later add more environment (preprod, test, ...) and have different configuration according to what you wanna test.

---

Also, if later you have more than 2 server deployment, you can have a (slightly) more complex config system, using a kind of hierarchical style:

First,  load the default (common) config `somedir/config.php`
Second, check if an additional config file exists for the current env (`somedir/[ENV]/config.php`) and if exists include it too.

Therefore, this is not a problem if your config file only returns an array of params, but you can have some issues if your config file contains constants (which is bad practice anyway :) ).

Comment: There is no way to remove one file from being pushed/pulled on a single machine, but not all git clones?

Comment: No, and that's why it's called `clone`. But you can also use hooks (post-update, pre-commit or whatever) to simulate an exotic behaviour you want

Answer (score 1):

Adding that to `.gitignore` is the way to go only if you are sure that the `config.php` file on production servers would be manually changed/overridden whenever is needed.
Using the `.gitignore` definitely wont push it when you publish your code.

Comment: Notice if you add the path of a file already tracked in your .gitignore , this will have no impact (the file will still be in git, and changes will still be tracked, until removal).