# How to remove a tracked file from a local repository, but keep it remote

Tags: git, github

I want to clear my local repository of unnecessary files, but leave them in the remote repository.

`git update-index --assume unchanged` allows you to change the file, but does not work on uninstall

Comment: Just delete it on disk, then optionally `git commit`.

Comment: We need more information: what, to you, are "unnecessary files"? Unstaged files? Are they files that you have already committed and pushed (in which case you can't clear them locally)?

Comment: @msanford
Yes, these are tracked files that are in the remote repository. I want to remove them so that the `git add .` command does not track their removal

Comment: You cannot. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476729/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544151/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+file+locally+but+not+remotely

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) is clear that you cannot use `git update-index` for the purpose you mentioned.